# Supervisor not reloading Gunicorn properly with Django project

Tags: django, gunicorn, supervisord

I am using **Supervisor** to reload **Gunicorn** when pushing **Django** project to production :

**Workflow** :

```
          " && python manage.py migrate"\
          " && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"\
          " && supervisorctl restart frontdesk-gunicorn"\
          " && exit"
```

**Supervisor config** :

```
   [program:project-gunicorn]
    command=/home/gaetangr/project/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi:application
    user = gaetangr
    directory = /home/gaetangr/project
    autostart = true
    autorestart = true
```

But most of the time, in order for all the change to propagate, I have to do a sudo :

`systemctl restart gunicorn`

From my understanding the command from supervisor should exactly the same.

Any idea ?

Comment: Bro post server related issue to https://serverfault.com/ they will better answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I figure it out so here you go.

I originally use a **service** to run **Gunicorn**, that was the case for quiet some time, but then I found this :

> **superviserd** manages processes by creating **subprocesses**. If you start **gunicorn** with **systemctl** then **superviserd** won't know anything about this  gunicorn and won't be able to restart it. Use only one process managment system - either **supervisord** or **systemd**.

In my case I had to delete the service running Gunicorn as well as the socket and update my Nginx configuration to remove the proxy service link to Gunicorn.